# «Склоните "Гузель" в дательном падеже» – корректно ли?

Tags: грамотная-речь, глаголы

[Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&start=15) пестрит подобными выражениями в вопросах. Но корректны ли они?

> Если фамилия человека Бересток. Как правильно **склонить** его фамилию в таком контексте: "Начальнику управления Бересток ( или Берестку )..."?
>
> Здравствуйте! Помогите правильно **склонить** глагол, у нас разногласия и кто прав не знаем. Настоящей доверенностью Общества с ограниченной ответсвенностью "ХХХ", в лице генерального директора Иванова Ивана Ивановича, действующего на основании Устава, доверя/ет/ или /ют/ Петрову получить товар. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Я бы переделал на "корректно ли употреблять склонить вместо склонять" или вроде того.

Comment: Начнем с конкретики дальше видно будет.

Answer (score 3):

Такое использование глагола [**СКЛОНИТЬ**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?bts=x&word=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) некорректно, у него нет лингвистического значения.

> [**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=311341)
>
> Глагол *склонить* совершенно неуместен при серьезном обсуждении склонения именных частей речи. Предполагаем, что в вопросах он может появляться случайно, по невнимательности авторов. Не исключаем и того, что его могут использовать в игровом ключе, как намеренное отступление от употребления хорошо известных терминов *склонять* и *склоняться*. Если остаются сомнения в терминологической корректности чьих-либо высказываний, то, безусловно, стоит обратиться за уточнениями к словарям русского языка. В них дается лингвистическое значение слов [**склонять**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?bts=x&word=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C) и [**склоняться**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?bts=x&word=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F), в чем можно убедиться, если прочитать статьи и в «Большом толковом словаре русского языка» (гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов) на нашем портале.

Comment: Ответ будет совсем полным, если добавить список примеров с аналогичными другими глаголами, где становится очевидна подобная неуместность без всяких словарей

Comment: @user190920 Считаю, что ответ полностью соответствует вопросу: "Корректны ли они?" Я задавал вопрос Грамоте три раза и долго ждал, копался в других источниках, неужели ответ не заслуживает даже плюса? // А вопрос об аналогичных других глаголах следует задать отдельно. Очевидность неуместности часто, если не всегда, необходимо подтверждать официальными источниками, так как люди по-разному могут использовать слова (для кого-то очевидно, для кого-то нет).

Comment: Плюс однозначно. Официальные источники всего лишь резюмируют практику. Практика же на другой стороне. Поэтому ответ не полон, склонить чашу весов на одну или другую сторону помогли бы аналогии с другими словами.

Comment: @user190920  Спасибо! "Список примеров с аналогичными другими глаголами" – это большой труд, целое исследование. А на этом сайте, думаю, нужно брать отдельные слова или пары и задавать вопрос именно о них.

Comment: Бог с ним со списком, пару явных иллюстративных примеров могли бы убедить в реальной некорректности, а не виртуальной по словарям, которая не соотносится с практикой